# joomla change author tag

Tags: php, joomla

i am trying to change the author meta tag. Now, when a user goes to share something to facebook, then the author meta tag is displayed his name. I want to change it to his username.

thank you

Comment: Just for reference, this has been answered here for you: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/author-meta-tag

Comment: @Lodder yes i saw it thank you!